# Making a drawString draw a double variable in Java

Tags: java

My main issue is trying to get the following snippit of code:

```
g2.drawString( "You ordered %f Cowboy Boots: ",ordering.getQuantity()[0], 0 ,0 );
```

The problem is, drawString is not applicable for these arguments. Is there another method I should be using instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), for example...

```
g2.drawString( String.format("You ordered %f Cowboy Boots:",ordering.getQuantity()[0]), 0, 0);
```

You might actually be better using a [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instead

```
g2.drawString( String.format("You ordered " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(ordering.getQuantity()[0]) + " Cowboy Boots:"), 0, 0);
```

Instead...